# picking without replacement in java

Tags: java, data-structures, complexity-theory, montecarlo, picking

I often* find myself in need of a data structure which has the following properties:

> - can be initialized with an array of n objects in O(n).
> - one can obtain a random element in O(1), after this operation the picked
>     element is removed from the structure.
>     (without replacement)
> - one can undo p 'picking without replacement' operations in O(p)
> - one can remove a specific object (eg by id) from the structure in O(log(n))
> - one can obtain an array of the objects currently in the structure in
>     O(n).

the complexity (or even possibility) of other actions (eg insert) does not matter. Besides the complexity it should also be efficient for small numbers of n.

Can anyone give me guidelines on implementing such a structure? I currently implemented a structure having all above properties, except the picking of the element takes O(d) with d the number of past picks (since I explicitly check whether it is 'not yet picked'). I can figure out structures allowing picking in O(1), but these have higher complexities on at least one of the other operations.

BTW:
note that O(1) above implies that the complexity is independent from #earlier picked elements and independent from total #elements.

*in monte carlo algorithms (iterative picks of p random elements from a 'set' of n elements).

Comment: what are some values of n, p, and d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, same answer as [0verbose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587884/0verbose) with a simple fix to get the O(1) random lookup. Create an array which stores the same n objects. Now, in the HashMap, store the  pairs .  For example, say your Objects (strings for simplicity) are:

```
{"abc" , "def", "ghi"}
```

Create an

```
List<String> array = ArrayList<String>("abc","def","ghi")
```

Create a HashMap map with the following values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) 
{
    map.put(array[i],i);
}
```

O(1) random lookup is easily achieved by picking any index in the array. The only complication that arises is when you delete an object. For that, do:

1. Find object in `map`. Get its array index. Lets call this index `i` (`map.get(i)`) - O(1)
2. Swap array[i] with array[size of array - 1] (the last element in the array). Reduce the size of the array by 1 (since there is one less number now) - O(1)
3. Update the index of the new object in position `i` of the array in `map` (map.put(array[i], i)) - O(1)

I apologize for the mix of java and cpp notation, hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

HashMap has complexity O(1) both for insertion and removal.
You specify a lot of operation, but all of them are nothing else then insertion, removal and traversing:

> can be initialized with an array of n objects in O(n).

n * O(1) insertion. HashMap is fine

> one can obtain a random element in
>   O(1), after this operation the picked
>   element is removed from the structure.
>   (without replacement)

This is the only op that require O(n).

> one can undo p 'picking without
>   replacement' operations in O(p)

it's an insertion operation: O(1).

> one can remove a specific object (eg
>   by id) from the structure in O(log(n))

O(1).

> one can obtain an array of the objects
>   currently in the structure in O(n).

you can traverse an HashMap in O(n)

EDIT:
example of picking up a random element in O(n):

```
HashMap map ....
int randomIntFromZeroToYouHashMapSize = ...
Collection collection = map.values();
Object[] values = collection.toArray();
values[randomIntFromZeroToYouHashMapSize];
```

Comment: I see indeed how you can use the hashmap to implement all operations but the random pick operation. In other words how do you pick a random element from a hashmap?

Comment: Re edit: That's not O(1) picking (`collection.toArray()` is always at least O(n)), and also it doesn't remove the picked value from the container.

Answer (score 1):

How about an array (or `ArrayList`) that's divided into "picked" and "unpicked"? You keep track of where the boundary is, and to pick, you generate a random index below the boundary, then (since you don't care about order), swap the item at that index with the last unpicked item, and decrement the boundary. To unpick, you just increment the boundary.

**Update:** Forgot about O(log(n)) removal. Not that hard, though, just a little memory-expensive, if you keep a `HashMap` of IDs to indices.

If you poke around on line you'll find various `IndexedHashSet` implementations that all work on more or less this principle -- an array or `ArrayList` plus a `HashMap`.

(I'd love to see a more elegant solution, though, if one exists.)

**Update 2:** Hmm... or does the actual removal become O(n) again, if you have to either recopy the arrays or shift them around?

Comment: A very interesting structure. Although removal is not guaranteed to be O(log(n)), but O(n) as far as I can see. It actually is similar to thrashgod's approach but more efficient, since memory is allocated once. In addition removal of unpicked elements can be achieved in O(1) if they are indexed.

Comment: @codelidoo: As `subList()` returns a view, I'd prefer `ArrayList`. Removal is still O(n), as you note.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the removal part. If you want removal in O(log(n)), you could add a HashMap from object (or ID) to index. Though for the actual removal you'll have to copy the arrays around to close the gap (either to new arrays, or shifting everything down and leaving 'dead' space at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my analysis of using [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) on an [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

- ✔ can be initialized with an array of n objects in O(n).

  Yes, although the cost is *amortized* unless n is known in advance.
- ✔ one can obtain a random element in O(1), after this operation the picked element is removed from the structure, without replacement.

  Yes, choose the last element in the shuffled array; replace the array with a `subList()` of the remaining elements.
- ✔ one can undo p 'picking without replacement' operations in O(p).

  Yes, append the element to the end of this list via `add()`.
- ❍ one can remove a specific object (eg by id) from the structure in O(log(n)).

  No, it looks like O(n).
- ✔ one can obtain an array of the objects currently in the structure in O(n).

  Yes, using `toArray()` looks reasonable.